# What is meant by increased vagal tone?

Tags: central-nervous-system

[Smiling](https://theconversation.com/our-vagus-nerves-help-us-rest-digest-and-restore-can-you-really-reset-them-to-feel-better-210469) ,for example,can stimulate vagus nerve as written in the following quote:

> Whether it’s through mindfulness, paced breathing, sports, sex or
> simply smiling, increased vagal tone is important for good health and
> wellbeing. There is a lot of hype online and some of it may be over
> the top. But reduced stress and greater relaxation are safe for
> everyone and have positive effects for our body and brain.

In above quote vagus nerve is stimulated by increased vagal tone.

My question is - What is meant by increased vagal tone ? Can pain also stimulate vagus nerve and increase vagal tone ?

Comment: Welcome Dheeraj. I'm not sure that this site is the best fit for this question. We have a [psychology.se] sister-site as well as a [medical.se] one. You might want to check them out, but before posting, ensure to take their tour and read their help centres to ensure that your post is on-topic.

Comment: @JiminyCricket ok.

Comment: Hi, that was supposed to read: [medicalsciences.se] in my previous comment.